# How do I successfully integrate a second database with Django South?

Tags: django, data-migration, django-south, geodjango

One of our clients needs to add some geolocation data to their
site. Since they already have a database setup without GIS extensions,
I decided to create a new database (with the GIS extensions), which I
intend to use to store only the geolocation data.

I had, at some point, set things up to work alright on my development
machine (meaning, I have migrations for these new models). But now that the code has been written, I imported a DB dump
directly from the server so that my development machine exactly
mirrors the production machine, and now I can't seem to get South to
apply the migrations correctly. South seems to have several features
which allow for multiple databases, but none of them have worked so far.

What I've tried:

1. Just adding the model and migrating. This gives me the following
   error:

   ```
   AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute
   'geo_db_type'
   ```

   OK, so South is trying to create the model on the original database
   which doesn't have the GIS extensions.
2. Adding the model, but specifying the 'geo' database for migrating
   the 'geo' app. This gives me the following error:

   ```
   django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "south_migrationhistory"
   does not exist
   ```

   I guess south expects its MigrationHistory table to exist on the 'geo'
   database as well?
3. Allow south's models to exist on my 'geo' database.

   ```
   $ python manage.py syncdb --database=geo
   $ python manage.py migrate
   ```

   This gives me the following error:

   ```
   django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "<model>" already exists
   ```

   I'm guessing this is because I already have MigrationHistories stored
   in the other database?
4. South apparently has a sparsely documented feature called 'dbs'
   (see:
   http://south.aeracode.org/docs/databaseapi.html#accessing-the-api )
   So I tried the previous three methods again replacing all instances of
   "db" with "dbs['geo']".

   a. Migrations run smoothly, but don't actually create any tables
   in my 'geo' database.

   b. Same error as when not using 'dbs' features.

   c. Same error as when not using 'dbs' features.

This entire process has been extremely frustrating. Has anyone got
multiple database support up-and-running when using South?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I posted?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have modified the table models I used south and these commands to modify the structure and they always worked:

```
python manage.py convert_to_south "your_app"
python manage.py migrate "your_app"
```

I recommend running these commands after running **syncdb**, so your tables are created.